# Loading all products taking huge time

Tags: magento-1.9, lazyload

I have a page where I have an option for pagination having an option "All".

Clicking on "ALL" loads all the available products but since it is trying to all the product collection and then display, it is taking huge time.

Anyone having a better solutions on this to tackle?

I am thinking to adopt a away for lazy loading but need a ray to start with!

Answer (score 2):

You can use some extension like follows. It will load more products when user scroll downs the page.

https://github.com/Strategery-Inc/Magento-InfiniteScroll

Demo: http://demo.usestrategery.com/infinite-scroll/infinitescroll.html

Comment: There is another free one: https://github.com/meanbee/magento-infinite-scroll

Comment: @Krishan Patadia Thanks buddy, I will apply those extensions and will try to proceed and will accept after successful testing

Comment: @sv3n Thanks buddy, I will apply those extensions and will try to proceed and will accept after successful testing